# Locating my old 401k from previous employer after administrator changed

Tags: united-states, 401k

I am trying to locate my old 401k from a company I left 7 years ago. I know they changed plan administrators, but the current administrator has no record of it.  The company is not returning my calls. I have searched the PBGC unclaimed pensions as well as our state unclaimed property list.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an old account statement from the original administrator? Did you try calling them? They ought to know if and where your assets were transferred.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I sure don't have documents from 7 years ago anymore...

Comment: @RonJohn If I have an account with assets, I **at least** keep the last statement received, plus whatever documentation from having opened the account. In no world would I shred *everything* related to an asset account that hasn't been confirmed transferred out and closed. I suppose having an actual filing cabinet puts me in the minority? :-)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea having a filing cabinet is probably common.  Regularly using it **and keeping it organize** for investments probably puts you in the minority.

Comment: When you left the company how much money was in the 401K? It is possible that they forced you to move the money to an IRA or other 401K account, they do this with small accounts.

Comment: "Regularly using it and keeping it organize for investments probably puts you in the minority." - Keeping the last statement from investment company, or last few years tax return, is hardly unusual. Considering how often people change jobs, I would hope that losing track of one's 401(k) is the exception, not the rule.  This doesn't take a file cabinet, a small file folder would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the change in plan administrators occurred and what happened to your particular account based on that transfer, the previous administrator might've tried to reach you at a place you could no longer be reached. In that case, in order for the prior plan administrator to free themselves of the responsibility of looking for you forever, they would've escheated the money to the state. There are services which will help you find any money in your name such as http://missingmoney.com/ and http://unclaimed.org/, but I have no personal experience with these sites. Each state should also have this information available, or available on reques. If the state has money in your name, it should be straightforward getting it back into your hands.